# Update mapStateToProps with Ramda

Tags: ramda.js

The following entry is used in project, it's clear that `state` argument use quite often

```
const props = state => ({
  name: getUserName(state),
  role: getUserRole(state),
  region: getUserRegion(state),
});
```

How can I update it with ramda?

Comment: BTW - are you using reselect? If you do, you can use  createStracturedSelectors.

Comment: @OriDrori yep, but not suitable for my case. it's `mapStateToProps` and it is quite different from component to component, using `applySpec` more correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [R.applySpec](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#applySpec):

```
const mapStateToProps = R.applySpec({
  name: getUserName,
  role: getUserRole,
  region: getUserRegion,
});
```